# How to style a lightning web component Radio button group

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-radiogroup

I'm having a radio group, and I need to customize it a bit, I want to remove the dott and keep only labels :

```
<lightning-radio-group class="myRadioGroup"
  name="my radios"
  options={RadioButtonOptions}
  value={value}
  onchange={handlerChange}
  type="radio">
 </lightning-radio-group>
```

My css goes like :

```
.myRadioGroup input[type=radio]{
   display: none !important;
  }
```

It's not workin', any ideas ?

Comment: you can't style child component from parent in LWC also which dot are you talking about?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the dot is actually the radio button "icon"

Comment: so if you dont want the whole radio button icon why use radio button?

Comment: I want to use the behave of radio button when i'll have many radio goups